# Android XML parsing problem with both SAX and Pull parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm parsing not so large XML files, about 200KB, in my application. Parser fails systematically when parsing some files.
Symptoms:

1. I use two types of XML parsers: **SAX
   (XMLReader) and Pull
   (XMLPullParser)**, both of them fail
   at the same place in the file
   (3182th byte).
2. I use `InputStream` as the input source for parsers.
3. I trieed to wrap `FileInputStream` with `BufferedInputStream` and nothing changed.

I don't know if the problem is in the `Parser` or in `InputStream`.

Please help to fix the problem or advise a workaround.

Comment: Please try with different xml file.